# C++ conversion from to non-scalar type requested

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to overload the + operator as a member function so that I can add two polynomial objects (which are linked lists) together and I keep getting an error message `conversion from 'Polynomial*' to non-scalar type 'std::shared_ptr<Polynomial>' requested` I don't understand what is causing this? I have declared two shared pointers for my Term objects so I don't understand why I can't do this for a polynomial object?

```
Polynomial Polynomial::operator+( const Polynomial &other ) const
{
    shared_ptr<Polynomial> result = new Polynomial();
    shared_ptr<Polynomial::Term> a = this->head;
    shared_ptr<Polynomial::Term> b = other.head;
    double sum = 0;

    for(a; a != nullptr; a = a->next)
    {
        for(b; b != nullptr; b = b->next)
        {
            if(a->exponent == b->exponent)
            {
                sum = a->coeff + b->coeff;
                result->head = shared_ptr<Term>(new Term( sum, a->exponent, result->head ));
                cout << "function has found like terms" << endl;
            }
            else if(a->exponent != b->exponent)
            {
                result->head = shared_ptr<Term>(new Term( a->coeff, a->exponent, result->head ));
                cout << "function is working" << endl;

            }
        }
  }
  result;
}
```

main.cpp

void makePolynomials( shared_ptr [], int &x );

```
int main()
   {
   shared_ptr<Polynomial> poly[ 100 ];
   int nPolynomials = 0;

   makePolynomials( poly, nPolynomials );
   makePolynomials( poly, nPolynomials );

   for (int j=0; j < nPolynomials; j++)
      cout << *(poly[j]);


    //shows that the addition operator works
    Polynomial c;
    c = *(poly[0])+*(poly[1]);
    cout << c << endl;
}


void makePolynomials( shared_ptr<Polynomial> poly[], int &nPolynomials )
   {
   char filename[20];
   cout << "Enter the filename: ";
   cin >> filename;

   ifstream infile;
   infile.open( filename );
   if (! infile.is_open()) {
      cerr << "ERROR: could not open file " << filename << endl;
      exit(1);
      }

   string polynom;
   while (getline( infile, polynom ))
      {
      poly[ nPolynomials ] = shared_ptr<Polynomial>(new Polynomial( polynom ));
      nPolynomials++;
      }
   }
```

Comment: What is the last line in the method, `result;`, supposed to be doing?

Comment: @mebob the last line, is suppose to be returning a new linked list that hopefully will contain nodes that represent the terms of a new polynomial (which was created by adding two existing polynomials using the addition operator) --correction Oops, that was suppose to be return result;

Comment: @user3341399 `result;` doesn't return anything. For that you need to use the `return` keyword. And even then the type of `result` is different than the method return type.

Comment: @zenith I meant to put in return result; Is that why the program crashes, because I am returning a shared_ptr instead of a polynomial object?

Comment: @user3341399 You can't return a `shared_ptr` where you have declared the function to return something else. It shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @zenith I am just so confused as to how to get this to return a polynomial object if I am referring to the object by using a a shared pointer. Should I return a dereference shared_ptr? If I dereferenced result, would that work? I don't even know if you can dereference a shared_ptr

Comment: Why did you actually declare `result` as a pointer in the first place? It seems to me that a plain `Polynomial` object would do just what you need, without all the extra pointer hassle.

Comment: @zenith Because if I did that I would be declaring the result list as a local variable. Thus, my polynomial object that I am trying to return would go out of scope and couldn't be accessed outside of the operator.

Comment: But you're returning it. Since when are return values not accessible outside the function?

Answer (score 10):

Here you're requesting an *implicit* conversion from `Polynomial*` to  `std::shared_ptr`:

> ```
> shared_ptr<Polynomial> result = new Polynomial();
> ```

But since the `std::shared_ptr` constructor is `explicit`, the conversion isn't possible.

You need to pass the `Polynomial*` explicitly to the `std::shared_ptr` constructor:

```
std::shared_ptr<Polynomial> result(new Polynomial);
```

or using the equivalent new uniform initialization syntax:

```
std::shared_ptr<Polynomial> result{new Polynomial};
```

Comment: thank you. With your correction the program compiled fine, but after it ran it crashed? Do you know why? my polynomial objects are being referred to by an array of shared pointers in main. I added that code above right now.

Comment: @user3341399 Probably because `operator+` isn't returning anything even though you promised the compiler it would return a `Polynomial`. Please turn your compiler warnings on.